# How can I compare installed hotfixes between two Windows servers using PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell

I need to compare the installed patches between a dev and production environment using PowerShell. How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I recently blogged about this problem and came up with this script. You can either run it as a user that is administrator on both machines, or use the `-Credential` option on the `get-hotfix` commands.

```
$server1 = Read-Host "Server 1"
$server2 = Read-Host "Server 2"

$server1Patches = get-hotfix -computer $server1 | Where-Object {$_.HotFixID -ne "File 1"}

$server2Patches = get-hotfix -computer $server2 | Where-Object {$_.HotFixID -ne "File 1"}

Compare-Object ($server1Patches) ($server2Patches) -Property HotFixID
```

Comment: Never knew about get-hotfix.  Great nugget of information there.

Comment: Be careful when using Get-Hotfix, it only reports a subset of patches. See this [Hey Scripting Guy article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/08/22/use-powershell-to-easily-find-information-about-hotfixes.aspx) for more information. @Mike

Answer (score 0):

```
clear-host
$machine1=Read-Host "Enter Machine Name 1:-"
$machine2=Read-Host "Enter Machine Name 2:-"
$machinesone=@(Get-wmiobject -computername  $machine1 -Credential Domain\Adminaccount -query 'select hotfixid from Win32_quickfixengineering')
$machinestwo=@(Get-WmiObject -computername $machine2  -Credential Domain\Adminaccount -query 'select hotfixid from Win32_quickfixengineering')
Compare-Object -RefernceObject $machinesone -DiffernceObject $machinestwo -Property hotfixid
```

Comment: Can you explain how querying WMI could be better than running native powershell against each host?